# Local struct in c

Tags: c

If a struct is only used in one function, can I declare it in that function? Can I do this:

```
int func()
{
    struct {
        int a, b;
    } s;

    s.a=5;

    return s.a;
}
```

gcc choked on it, but it emitted a very weird looking error that I couldn't understand instead of saying "Sorry, you can't do that".

Comment: Would be helpful if you provided the error message.

Comment: @Rayn I just tried it again to see if I could get the error, and this time it compiled. It was a very weird looking error for a syntax problem (it was a linker error with what looked like a mangled c++ name in it)

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. Try renaming things; maybe you collided with an existing name. Are you using a C++ compiler?

Comment: @PaulR you're right! :-O

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is perfectly valid C89/C99/C11 code, this a structure with no tag and the object has block scope. Check C99 6.7.2.3p6 to see the identifier for the tag is optional.